# Objective-C Code Structure in Implementation File

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
@interface OuterSpaceController ()

//Cannot alloc and init my array here for some reason
NSMutableArray *spaceObjectsAsPropertyLists = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

@end

//But could do it here... Can someone explain why this is the case?
NSMutableArray *spaceObjectsAsPropertyLists = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

@implementation OuterSpaceController


@end
```

Hi I had a question regarding this code structure in objective-C. My first question is why is this portion even present in the implementation file?:

```
@interface OuterSpaceController ()

@end
```

I tried creating my NSMutableArray there^^^, so I can access it in all my methods in the implementation file, but I was not able to for some reason. Also regarding my NSMutableArray if I create it in between the @end and @implementation OuterSpaceController lines of code (like shown in my first block of code), will my NSMutableArray be allocated and initialized every time my view controller is loaded in memory? And if not when does the allocation and initialization of this NSMutableArray *spaceObjectsAsPropertyLists Mutable Array happen?

Thank you so much for the help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called a class extension:

```
@interface OuterSpaceController ()
@end
```

Extensions allow you to add declarations to your class. See [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html) for details. This is mostly used for declaring properties or methods in a different scope of the original declaration. Something like this:

```
// Foo.h
@interface Foo
@property (strong) NSArray * everyoneCanSeeThis;
@end

// Foo.m
@interface Foo ()
@property (strong) NSArray * thisIsOnlyVisibleInThisFile;
@end
```

There are other uses to extensions. I recommend you read Apple's docs.

Your other question is not related to this. In order to initialise the `spaceObjectsAsPropertyLists` property you have two options. One, when initialising the class:

```
@interface OuterSpaceController ()

// Does not initialise, just declares. This is an interface, not an implementation
@property (strong) NSMutableArray *spaceObjectsAsPropertyLists;

@end

@implementation OuterSpaceController

- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        _spaceObjectsAsPropertyLists = [NSMutableArray array];
    }

    return self;
}

@end
```

In this case the array is instantiated as soon as the class is initialised, but there's a second option. There's another way of initialising classes called Lazy Initialisation. Here's how it goes:

```
@interface OuterSpaceController ()

// Does not initialise, just declares. This is an interface, not an implementation
@property (strong) NSMutableArray *spaceObjectsAsPropertyLists;

@end

@implementation OuterSpaceController

- (instancetype)init
{
    // Do not instantiate!
    return [super init];
}

- (NSMutableArray *)spaceObjectsAsPropertyLists
{
    if (_spaceObjectsAsPropertyLists == nil) {
         _spaceObjectsAsPropertyLists = [NSMutableArray array];
    }
    return _spaceObjectsAsPropertyLists;
}

@end
```

The general idea is to override the property's getter. The upside of this method is that the property will be initialised *only* as soon as it is needed, and not sooner. This method is usually more memory friendly.

You need to know that your interfaces can only contain declarations. It's the implementation section who's responsible for pretty much everything else.

Comment: Hey Andre, sorry for the late reply. This makes a lot more sense now. I just had one more question, would putting my NSMutableArray in between the @end and "@"implementation OuterSpaceController lines of code be a bad idea? Or is it better to override the getter method as you suggested? Again thank you so much for the help!

Comment: It would be a terrible idea as it would not compile :) first of all you need to realise what an implementation is and what an interface is. You declare stuff in interfaces. That's where you "there exists a property of a given type, with a given name, and certain property accessors". Implementations is where you declare how your class behaves. When is data allocated? When is it freed? When and how does the class do what it's supposed to do? So on, you cannot declare properties in implementations. Property declarations always go in interfaces

Comment: Oh arite. That makes complete sense. Thank you so much for the help Andre!

Comment: Hey sorry for getting back this late, but in your lazy instantiation example in the - (NSMutableArray *)spaceObjectsAsPropertyLists method shouldn't it be if(!_spaceObjectsAsPropertyLists) for the first if statement? Since you only want to initialize a new array if it didn't exist before? I am not 100% sure, but that is just my guess :)

Comment: Absolutely! I just edited the answer, thanks for the heads up ;)

Comment: Alright cool. Thanks for the help! I finally understand the difference now!